# Java Timer on an Android app

Tags: java, android, timer

I need a little help on my android app in java.

I have a timer that check if current score is better than the best score saved and save it accordingly

Here is the code :

```
    if(sec< bestSec){
        Main.settings= Main.context.getSharedPreferences(GameConstants.PREFS_NAME, Main.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
        Main.editor= Main.settings.edit();
        if(mSec<10){
            Main.editor.putString("best", sec+"."+"0"+mSec);
        }else{
            Main.editor.putString("best", sec+"."+mSec);
        }
        Main.editor.putInt("bestSec", sec);
        Main.editor.putInt("bestMSec", mSec);
        Main.editor.commit();
    }else if(sec== bestSec){
        if(mSec< bestMSec){
            Main.settings= Main.context.getSharedPreferences(GameConstants.PREFS_NAME, Main.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
            Main.editor= Main.settings.edit();
            if(mSec<10){
                Main.editor.putString("best", sec+"."+"0"+mSec);
            }else{
                Main.editor.putString("best", sec+"."+mSec);
            }
            Main.editor.putInt("bestSec", sec);
            Main.editor.putInt("bestMSec", mSec);
        }
    }
```

My best score is : 12,89sec for exemple.
If I do 11,20 or 11,92 it save nice, but if I do 12,45sec it doesn't save.

Thx for your help !

Comment: Are you comparing ints, doubles or floats?

Comment: In your code what is `Main`?

Comment: i compare int and Main is main.java in src

Comment: I mean what sort of class is `Main`? Is it a general class or does it extend another class?

Comment: Why don't you just use a long for milliseconds and always compare those? No reason to keep separate variables for seconds and milliseconds...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use double or float values to compare them correctly. If you are casting your decimal values to int, 12,89 and 12,45 will be equal to 12. The decimal part of the number will be ignored.

Use doubles or floats to make effective comparisons and use `editor.putFloat()` to save the values.